# What information does Android's MediaStore use to determine mime type?

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm using the `MediaStore` to load a list of files on the user's device and using `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE` in my projection.  I have a file that is a 3gp video which has a file name ending in `.3gp`, and the data I'm getting back is that its mime type is `video/mp4`.

Comment: Any idea how that file got there? `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` methods allow the caller to specify the MIME type, so perhaps some app used that and had the wrong MIME type.

Comment: @CommonsWare I downloaded it for testing.  I downloaded it in Chrome, previewed it in QuickPic, and then went into my app for testing shortly after.  My app queries MediaStore using a CursorLoader.  Are you saying that 3rd parties can alter the data I get back from MediaStore?  For example, QuickPic could have mistakenly set the wrong mime type on this file prior to my app querying for it?

Comment: "Are you saying that 3rd parties can alter the data I get back from MediaStore?" -- I am saying that if an app asks the `MediaStore` to index a file, that app can specify a MIME type. The app doesn't have to, in which case I would guess that `MediaStore` falls back to `MimeTypeMap` and a file extension lookup. But the fact that MIME types are in the `MediaScannerConnection` API suggest that `MediaStore` honors them.

Comment: "For example..." -- I would not expect that scenario. However, perhaps the Web server served up the file with a MIME type of `video/mp4`, and perhaps Chrome just passed that MIME type along to `MediaStore` via `MediaScannerConnection`. You might try using `curl` or something to see how the server served that file.

Comment: I looked at the `MimeTypeMap` source and tested in the Watches window as well, and `MimeTypeMap` gets it right.  I'm going to fall back to the way `MimeTypeMap` works which is by just using the file extension.  I thought there might be something more sophisticated available than that, but I suppose it's the best available if MediaStore mime types can be wrong?

Comment: @CommonsWare That is a great assumption that the web server may have returned the bad data.  That's also another reason to use the file extension as the most likely to be correct.

Comment: "I suppose it's the best available if MediaStore mime types can be wrong?" -- um, well, file extensions can be wrong too. I am not aware of a magic bullet here. Using one MIME type (`MediaStore` or `MimeTypeMap`) as the primary, and trying the other one as a fallback in case of problems (and where the values differ), is probably your best option. Bear in mind that `MimeTypeMap` will not recognize all file extensions, and that the server may know better than `MimeTypeMap` what the real MIME type of the data was.

Comment: @CommonsWare curl says web server reports the correct mime type.  Since both can be incorrect, I'm falling back to file extension as the most likely to be correct knowing that as you say there is no magic bullet.  My use case is simply "only allow mp4 videos"